# Is Amazon EC2 suitable for running a .NET project (MVC3) with Jenkins CI?

Tags: .net, hudson, amazon-ec2, umbraco, jenkins

I want to run a CI Jenkins server on Amazon EC2 on Windows 2008. The code I am going to test does not have a big memory overhead - I will be executing mainly selenium functional/smoke tests for an Umbraco CMS site. I have used Jenkins for a couple of other projects before and enjoy the fact that it seems to have matured with a large, open-source audience and has many plug-ins but I tend to find support for them a tad limited.

I have seen a few resources for doing something similar to this but with an Ubuntu instance and using either Python or Ruby on Rails. I appreciate that Amazon has only fairly recently begun supporting Windows 2008 server on it's EC2 service but there seem to be  few guides for running an IIS7 site with Jenkins using a cloud computing service like EC2.

Has anyone had any experience with implementing CI with a setup such as this? Which EC2 instance should I use? Would micro instance be sufficient (have enough memory) or should I use a bigger instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup jetkins you need JRE 1.5 or later.if you will us this server just for continuous integration you does not need to such a big server. Micro instance will be enough. But you should choose X86_64 Bit AMI for future upgrades to large instances.

But also if you will use as an app server you also need to install asp.net mvc3.
You can download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1491) to run asp.net mvc3 application on windows server 2008. In this case it is better to have an instance with bigger memory options such as large instance.